# No route matches [GET] "/packs/js/application.js"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get an error when trying to reference the javascript packs in my code. Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

**application.js**

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()

require("jquery-3.5.1.min")
require("jquery-ui-1.12.1")
require("dataTables.fnSetFilteringDelay")
require("jquery.dataTables.columnFilter-1.5.6")
require("application_default")
```

**application.html.erb**

```
 <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'jquery-3', 'jquery-ui-1', 'jquery', 'FixedHeader-2', 'ColVis-1', 'rails': 'reload' %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're missing corresponding `public/packs/js/*.js` files. Two options to fix it:

To just compile your packs and let rails server handle recompilation on refresh

```
bin/webpack
```

In development it's better to run dev server. It compiles when your files change.

```
bin/webpack-dev-server
```

Note on your file structure and what different *tag* helpers do:

```
app/
  assets/                # used by sprockets aka rails asset pipeline
    stylesheets/
      application.css    # stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
                         #  this is not old syntax; very much current and recommended in rails 7
    javascripts/
      application.js     # javascript_include_tag 'application'

  javascript/            # used by rails webpacker
    packs/               # keep this folder neat; don't dump everything in here
      application.js     # javascript_pack_tag 'application'
                         #  use this file to import packages from node_modules
    styles/
      application.css    # stylesheet_pack_tag 'application'
                         #  must be imported in packs/application.js
                         #  import "styles/application"
  
  node_modules/          # use yarn or npm to add js packages, don't put them in 'packs'
```

Comment: When i run bin/webpack-dev-server I get an error saying "Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.2". Been trying to get around that bug as well. Something odd is going on because for my stylesheets if I use this syntax "<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'jquery.autocomplete' %>" my css is missing but if I use the old syntax  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery.autocomplete' %> it works fine

Comment: rails expects a certain file structure for everything to work. i've updated my answer to clarify. do you have ruby 3.0.2 installed?

Comment: If I run “ruby -v” it says 2.6.3. But in my gemfile I point to ruby ‘3.0.2’.

Comment: you need to install the matching ruby version by yourself; `ruby -v` must match with Gemfile ruby version. bundler only installs gems and verifies current ruby version. it does not install ruby or switch ruby versions. v2.6 is old and soon to be EOL anyway.

Comment: Okay I change my ruby version to 3.0.2 but now I get a different error when running bin/webpack-dev-server.
"Unable to find a spec satisfying nokogiri (>= 0) in the set. Perhaps the lockfile is corrupted? Found nokogiri (1.13.3-x86_64-linux), nokogiri (1.13.3-x86_64-linux), nokogiri (1.13.3-x86_64-linux), nokogiri (1.13.3-x86_64-linux), nokogiri (1.13.3-x86_64-linux), nokogiri (1.13.3-x86_64-linux) that did not match the current platform."

Comment: did you run `bin/bundle install` after updating ruby?

Comment: running bin/bundle install helped and had to manually install some other gems. 
Now getting a new error ruby/3.0.2/gems/webpacker-5.4.3/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:13:in ``': No such file or directory - yarn (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: you shouldn't have to manually install gems, with very very few exceptions (for example `foreman` gem). any gems in `Gemfile` should be installed by bundler, otherwise you'll encounter problems later when updating. if you had issues with `bundle install` maybe post another question. Also looks like you're missing `yarn`. Two things you have to have independent of your app is `ruby` and `yarn` that's it. ruby dependencies are taken care of in `Gemfile`  using `bundler` and js dependencies in `package.json` using `yarn`.

Answer (score 0):

**If nothing else worked for you:**

1. Run `bin/webpack && rake assets:precompile`
2. Make sure rails is not trying to compile assets at runtime and it can read your assets from public folder:

```rb
# production.rb 
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
config.assets.compile = false
```

3. Run `rails s`